# How can I make objects permanently stick in window without being refreshed in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to recreate Atari Breakout using Pygame. I met with a problem, I put all three rows of the tiles in three lists and I want to print them and make them stay at the location before the ball hits them.

This is the code:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

screenWidth = 1200
screenHeight = 700

window = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth,screenHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Atari Breakout')

pygame.mouse.set_pos(-500,650)


class Plate():

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5

    def draw_plate(self):
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.x = pos[0]-100

        pygame.draw.rect(window, (00,00,255), (self.x, self.y ,self.width, self.height))


class Circle():

    def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.vel_x = 5
        self.vel_y = 5


class Tiles():

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color

    def draw(self):
        if self.color == 'red':
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        elif self.color == 'green':
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (44,176,55), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        elif self.color == 'blue':
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,191,255), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        pygame.display.update()


def draw_titles():
    first_row = []
    second_row = []
    third_row = []
    preset_width1 = [70, 120, 200, 30, 240, 140, 130, 120, 80]                       # nine elements
    preset_width2 = [70, 120, 200, 30, 240, 140, 130, 120, 80]
    preset_width3 = [70, 120, 200, 30, 240, 140, 130, 120, 80]
    random.shuffle(preset_width1)
    random.shuffle(preset_width2)
    random.shuffle(preset_width3)
    #print(f'preset_width1 is: {preset_width1}')
    put_width1 = []
    put_width2 = []
    put_width3 = []

    for t in range(1,10):

        if t==1:
            width = preset_width1.pop(0)
            put_width1.append(width)
            #print(f'put_width1 is: {put_width1}')


        if t==1:
            x = 0 + 5
        else:
            add = sum(put_width1)
            #print(f'add is: {add}')
            x = t*5 + add
            #print(f'x is: {x}')

        if t>1:
            width = preset_width1.pop(0)
            put_width1.append(width)
            #print(f'put_width1 is: {put_width1}')

        y = 125

        height = 35


        first_row.append(Tiles(x,y,width,height,'red'))

        if t == 9:
            break

    for t in range(1,10):

        if t==1:
            width = preset_width2.pop(0)
            put_width2.append(width)

        if t==1:
            x = 0 + 5
        else:
            add = sum(put_width2)
            x = t*5 + add

        if t>1:
            width = preset_width2.pop(0)
            put_width2.append(width)

        y = 170

        height = 35

        second_row.append(Tiles(x,y,width,height,'green'))

        if t == 9:
            break

    for t in range(1,10):

        if t==1:
            width = preset_width3.pop(0)
            put_width3.append(width)

        if t==1:
            x = 0 + 5
        else:
            add = sum(put_width3)
            x = t*5 + add

        if t>1:
            width = preset_width3.pop(0)
            put_width3.append(width)

        y = 215

        height = 35

        third_row.append(Tiles(x,y,width,height,'blue'))

        if t == 9:
            break


    for num in range(0,9):
        first_row[num].draw()

    for num in range(0,9):
        second_row[num].draw()

    for num in range(0,9):
        third_row[num].draw()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_BACKSPACE]:
        run = False







# main loop
plate = Plate(10,650,200,40)
ball = Circle(600,300,10)
run = True
start = False
bounds = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 1200, 700)


while run:
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(120)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    plate.draw_plate()



    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


    # bounce algorithem 
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        start = True

    if start:
        ball.y -= ball.vel_y        
        ball.x += ball.vel_x

        if ball.x - ball.radius < bounds.left or ball.x + ball.radius > bounds.right:
            ball.vel_x *= -1 
        if ball.y - ball.radius < bounds.top or ball.y + ball.radius > bounds.bottom:
            ball.vel_y *= -1 

    pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 0), bounds, 1)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (44,176,55), (ball.x, ball.y), ball.radius)
    #pygame.display.update()


    draw_titles()



    # close call
    if keys[pygame.K_BACKSPACE]:
        run = False
        break





    window.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.display.update()




pygame.quit()
```

This is the ideal situation:

[image: ideal situation]

But instead, it refreshes like crazy. I know the problem is I put the `draw_titles()` function inside of the main While loop. But I believe is the way I code the `draw_tiles()` function that made it not work. If I place `draw_titles()` before the loop, the tiles will appear and instantly disappear and both the ball and the plate will not display.

I did some research online and I see tutorial for text and images. For images, they use `.blit()` but I believe it is only for images.

I had tried many variations to fix this but to no avail. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: `if event == pygame.QUIT:` should be `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:`. `window.fill((0,0,0))` has to be done before drawing the first object (before `plate.draw_plate()`). Do a single `pygame.display.update()` at the end of the main application loop (delete `pygame.display.update()` in `Tiles.draw`)

Comment: What will happen if I stack ```pygame.display.update()```

Comment: Flickering objects

Comment: Oh alright I will change that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick fix:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

screenWidth = 1200
screenHeight = 700

window = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth,screenHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Atari Breakout')

pygame.mouse.set_pos(-500,650)


class Plate():

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5

    def draw_plate(self):
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.x = pos[0]-100

        pygame.draw.rect(window, (00,00,255), (self.x, self.y ,self.width, self.height))


class Circle():

    def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.vel_x = 5
        self.vel_y = 5


class Tiles():

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color

    def draw(self):
        if self.color == 'red':
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        elif self.color == 'green':
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (44,176,55), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        elif self.color == 'blue':
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,191,255), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

first_row = []
second_row = []
third_row = []

def create_titles():
    preset_width1 = [70, 120, 200, 30, 240, 140, 130, 120, 80]                       # nine elements
    preset_width2 = [70, 120, 200, 30, 240, 140, 130, 120, 80]
    preset_width3 = [70, 120, 200, 30, 240, 140, 130, 120, 80]
    random.shuffle(preset_width1)
    random.shuffle(preset_width2)
    random.shuffle(preset_width3)
    #print(f'preset_width1 is: {preset_width1}')
    put_width1 = []
    put_width2 = []
    put_width3 = []

    for t in range(1,10):

        if t==1:
            width = preset_width1.pop(0)
            put_width1.append(width)
            #print(f'put_width1 is: {put_width1}')


        if t==1:
            x = 0 + 5
        else:
            add = sum(put_width1)
            #print(f'add is: {add}')
            x = t*5 + add
            #print(f'x is: {x}')

        if t>1:
            width = preset_width1.pop(0)
            put_width1.append(width)
            #print(f'put_width1 is: {put_width1}')

        y = 125

        height = 35


        first_row.append(Tiles(x,y,width,height,'red'))

        if t == 9:
            break

    for t in range(1,10):

        if t==1:
            width = preset_width2.pop(0)
            put_width2.append(width)

        if t==1:
            x = 0 + 5
        else:
            add = sum(put_width2)
            x = t*5 + add

        if t>1:
            width = preset_width2.pop(0)
            put_width2.append(width)

        y = 170

        height = 35

        second_row.append(Tiles(x,y,width,height,'green'))

        if t == 9:
            break

    for t in range(1,10):

        if t==1:
            width = preset_width3.pop(0)
            put_width3.append(width)

        if t==1:
            x = 0 + 5
        else:
            add = sum(put_width3)
            x = t*5 + add

        if t>1:
            width = preset_width3.pop(0)
            put_width3.append(width)

        y = 215

        height = 35

        third_row.append(Tiles(x,y,width,height,'blue'))

        if t == 9:
            break

# main loop
plate = Plate(10,650,200,40)
ball = Circle(600,300,10)
run = True
start = False
bounds = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 1200, 700)

create_titles()

while run:
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(120)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    # bounce algorithem 
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        start = True
    # close call
    if keys[pygame.K_BACKSPACE]:
        run = False
        break

    if start:
        ball.y -= ball.vel_y        
        ball.x += ball.vel_x

        if ball.x - ball.radius < bounds.left or ball.x + ball.radius > bounds.right:
            ball.vel_x *= -1 
        if ball.y - ball.radius < bounds.top or ball.y + ball.radius > bounds.bottom:
            ball.vel_y *= -1 

    window.fill((0,0,0))
    plate.draw_plate()
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 0), bounds, 1)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (44,176,55), (ball.x, ball.y), ball.radius)
    for tile in first_row:
        tile.draw()
    for tile in second_row:
        tile.draw()
    for tile in third_row:
        tile.draw()

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

When drawing to the screen, clear the screen surface first, then draw all objects, like this:

```
    ...
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    plate.draw_plate()
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 0), bounds, 1)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (44,176,55), (ball.x, ball.y), ball.radius)
    for tile in first_row:
        tile.draw()
    for tile in second_row:
        tile.draw()
    for tile in third_row:
        tile.draw() 
    ...
```

Note how all drawing related stuff is in one place. This way, it's clearer and less confusing.

You should make sure to only call pygame.display`.flip()` (or `.update()`) only once per frame (as Rabbid76 already said in a comment).

I also moved the lists outside the `draw_titles` function, which I renamed to `create_titles`. The function creates the tiles, so it should only be done once, not every frame.

You should also probably look into pygame's `Sprite` and `Group` class. Here's an example I hacked together which makes use of some pygame features:

```
import pygame
import random

class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, bounds, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((0,0,255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
        self.bounds = bounds

    def update(self, dt):
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        self.rect.centerx = pos[0]
        self.rect.clamp_ip(self.bounds)

class Circle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, bounds, *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((radius, radius))
        self.image.set_colorkey((1, 2, 3))
        self.image.fill((1, 2, 3))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, (44,176,55), (radius//2, radius//2), 5)
        self.vel = pygame.Vector2((5, 5))
        self.pos = self.rect.center
        self.bounds = bounds

    def update(self, dt):
        self.pos += self.vel * min(dt/15, 10)
        self.rect.center = self.pos

        if self.rect.left < self.bounds.left or self.rect.right > self.bounds.right:
            self.vel.x *= -1
        if self.rect.top < self.bounds.top or self.rect.bottom > self.bounds.bottom:
            self.vel.y *= -1

        self.rect.clamp_ip(self.bounds)

    def bounce(self, sprite):
        if self.rect.top <= sprite.rect.top or sprite.rect.bottom >= sprite.rect.bottom:
            self.vel.y *= -1
        elif self.rect.left <= sprite.rect.left or sprite.rect.right >= sprite.rect.right:
            self.vel.x *= -1


class Tiles(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color,  *grps):
        super().__init__(*grps)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))

    def hit(self):
        self.kill()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 700))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    pygame.display.set_caption('Atari Breakout')

    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    tiles = pygame.sprite.Group()
    paddle = Paddle(10,650,200,40, screen_rect, sprites)
    ball = Circle(600,300,10, screen_rect, sprites)

    preset = [70, 120, 200, 30, 240, 140, 130, 120, 80]
    y = 215
    for color in ['blue', 'green', 'red']:
        x = 5
        line = preset[:]
        random.shuffle(line)
        for width in line:
            Tiles(x, y, width, 35, pygame.Color(color), sprites, tiles)
            x += width + 5
        y -= 45

    dt = 0
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(120)

        # events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    return

        # game logic
        tile = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ball, tiles)
        if tile:
            tile.hit()
            ball.bounce(tile)

        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(paddle, ball):
            ball.bounce(paddle)

        sprites.update(dt)

        # drawing
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), screen_rect, 1)

        pygame.display.update()
        dt = clock.tick(120)

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So other than moving the ```first_row = []; second_row = []; third_row = []```, my problem is messy code and putting ```pygame.display.update()``` and ```window.fill((0,0,0))``` at the wrong place?

Comment: Yes. Try to stick to the following flow: handle events, update your game state, clear the screen and draw to the screen.

Comment: I added another example that uses some pygame features, like Vectors and Sprites etc.